# POSTGRES_URL connection string not working for localhost database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, svelte, sveltekit

This connection string is giving me an error (pasted at the bottom) when I include it in the .env.local file of my Svelte app.

```
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://myusername:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabasename"
```

(I've substituted 'mypassword' etc, but the real one doesn't have anything weird about it like weird characters)

I have tried all of the following and they all work ...

- **pgAdmin** connects ok to that postgres db on localhost 5432
- **pg_isready** works ok

```
> pg_isready -d 'postgres://myusername:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabasename'
> localhost:5432 - accepting connections
```

- **psql** works ok

```
psql -d 'postgres://myusername:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabasename' -c "Select 1"

 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

- **Vercel DB** connection string in the same file .env.local - works ok

```
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://default:vmU398umcu89@ep-aaaaaa-a-aaaaa-aaaaa-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com/verceldb"
```

I have also tried breaking the connection string in different ways ...

```
 myusername -> myusernamexx -> same error as below
 mypassword -> mypassworxx  -> same error as below
 removing password          -> same error as below
 localhost  -> localhostxx  -> "VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'invalid_connection_string'"
 5432 -> 5000               -> same error as below
 removing port              -> same error as below
 mydatabase -> mydatabasxx  -> same error as below
```

I have watched the local database terminal window while I was breaking things. If I do a psql with a garbage username then the database log shows `FATAL:  database "garbageuser" does not exist`. But, nothing I do in the .env.local file causes any output in the database output.

Thank you in advance for any help.

The error I get in my Svelte App ...

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorAndClose (/Users/tee/Documents/Projects/myappsvelte/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1016:13)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/tee/Documents/Projects/myappsvelte/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:864:5)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -61,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -61,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 443
    }
  ]
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem related to your DB connection at all. Something is trying to connect to `localhost:443`

Comment: thanks @phil. On further investigation I think the issue is that I'm trying to use @vercel/postgress on a local database and it doesn't work. https://gal.hagever.com/posts/running-vercel-postgres-locally https://github.com/vercel/storage/issues/123 https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1104381976984682516. I just gave up with vercel/postgres and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg